# ajax, jquery and Iframe (creating a message box system)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to create a sort of mail on my site.

So I have a table that contains three columns, let's say (for simplicity , but in reality) , with the two int fields ( from, to ) and a timestamp (date of sending )

a part of my page , I display a list of messages with a group by `to` to group all messages that are destined for the same person .

Eventually I want to display the entire conversation when clicking on the message but it is not obvious.

I tried jquery ajax and then an iframe but it is not great , because on one hand it does not return me anything (white pages) and secondly the reload each second is not great .

At first I would like to display the result of my request.

I have not set callback because I do not know what to do with an application in a jquery callback . I thought the easiest way was to do my processing in php and run my loop then displays everything in the iframe .

So I put it in jquery

```
$( ".load_message" ).click(function() {
            //On marque uniquement l'id de l'expediteur et du destinataire
            // pour chercher les messages expédiés par A vers B ou inversement
            var from = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.from').text();
            var to = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.to').text();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pages_ajax/fetch-messages.php',
                data: { from: from,  to: to},
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
         setInterval(refreshIframe1, 1000);
       function refreshIframe1() {
           $("#messages")[0].src = $("#messages")[0].src;
       }
```

and the php page I have this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../lib_php/librairie.php");
require_once("../../config/connexion.php");
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

/**
 * Fonction qui retourne une liste de messages
 * @return int
 */
function fetchMessages() {
    if (isset($_POST['from'])) {
        $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
        $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);

        $query = "SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent`, `read`, `direction`
    FROM `cometchat`
    WHERE `from` = {$from} || `from` = {$to} || `to` = {$to} || `to` = {$from}";

        return $query;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['from'])) {
    $liste_messages = fetchMessages();
    if (!is_null($liste_messages)) {
        $result_message = mysql_query($liste_messages);
        while ($mess = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_message)):
            ?>

            ici
            <?php
        endwhile;
    }
}
?>
```

But for now nothing works I do not even have my messages while running the echo of my query in phpMyAdmin return me something. I guess I'm loosing context when reloading ($_POST are loosing themselves)

I would initially display the entire conversation in an iframe or a div, then after whatever it is automatically updated if ever there's new posts in the meantime a bit like the messaging system on Facebook with no reloading of the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while you asked the question hope u solved it. Anyway is what i can tell from your code and what you try to do:

1. Your jquery function have no callback (success, complete)
2. Your php code don't return anything, you just do a loop like you want to manipulate each record, and reading your post you want to have your ajax to read all value in a success callback... So don't need a loop except you want to parse it, just expose them with `json_encode($mess);`
3. setInterval 1s? argh!!! Will your server handle it? Use something like 10 à 30s or 4:
4. go for websocket solution like racket in php or use nodejs plateform (nodejs + socket.io + redis)
   Hope it helped you out or someone else